# Powershell Select-String Problem with variable

Tags: powershell, variables, select-string

I have a CSV list of numbers that I would like to use Select-String to return the name of the file that the string is in.

When I do this

```
$InvoiceList = Import-CSV "C:\invoiceList.csv"
Foreach ($invoice in $InvoiceList) 
        {
            $orderFilename = $FileList | Select-String -Pattern "3505343956" | Select Filename,Pattern
            $orderFilename
        }
```

It gives me a response, I realize it is in a loop, but it gives me a response (albeit many times). This is what I would like.

Order# 199450619.pdf.txt 3505343956
Order# 199450619.pdf.txt 3505343956

But, when I run this:

```
$InvoiceList = Import-CSV "C:\invoiceList.csv"
Foreach ($invoice in $InvoiceList) 
        {
            $orderFilename = $FileList | Select-String -Pattern "$invoice" | Select Filename,Pattern
            $orderFilename
        }
```

or this

```
$InvoiceList = Import-CSV "C:\invoiceList.csv"
Foreach ($invoice in $InvoiceList) 
        {
            $orderFilename = $FileList | Select-String -Pattern $invoice | Select Filename,Pattern
            $orderFilename
        }
```

I get nothing in return.

I know there is data in $invoice because if I just ouput $invoice, I get all the invoice numbers that are in the CSV.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `$InvoiceList` contains the output from a [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) call, it contains *custom objects* with *properties named for the CSV columns*, not *strings*.

Therefore, you must explicitly access the property that contains the invoice number (as a string) in order to use it as search pattern with [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string).

Assuming that the property / column name of interest is `InvoiceNum` (adjust as needed):

```sh
Foreach ($invoice in $InvoiceList.InvoiceNum) { # Note the .InvoiceNum
  $FileList | Select-String -Pattern $invoice | Select Filename,Pattern
}
```

Note:

- Even though `$InvoiceList` contains an *array* of objects, PowerShell allows you to access a property that only exists on the *elements* of the array (`.InvoiceNum` here), and get the *elements'* property values as a result - this convenient feature is called [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration).

However, note that `Select-String`'s `-Pattern` parameter accepts an *array* of search patterns, so you can shorten your command as follows, which also improves performance:

```sh
$FileList |
  Select-String -Pattern (Import-Csv C:\invoiceList.csv).InvoiceNum |
    Select-Object Filename,Pattern
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Spent all morning on this.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it helped, @JeffKu; my pleasure, and thanks for taking the formatting advice.